# How to change echart axis label position

Tags: svg, echarts

[image]

How can I place the axis label on the circled blank. I try many methods and couldn't achive it. Did anyone good at echarts tell me how to do?

Here is the offical example:
[echarts bar](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`series.label`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label) with a `formatter` to achieve this.

The series label is associated to a specific series and can be placed anywhere (position [0,0] being the top-left of the bar of that series). The [formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.formatter) will allow you to display the series name in that label instead of the default value.

Of course, you have to put that label on only one series (otherwise it'll be displayed above each bar of the same 'category'). You'll also have to hide yAxis label. See full code [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQDqwATlgCawAKoArlgIaQyVEBfADREwwYFkggCqYhjoQA5opx0qXUhADOlEXI3a2EaGFUyicsAE8Q-WJS0ALLo2AB3fnIGC9sXCuhGGWEiRQUgwjlcADMKewBmAFJdC1gFRUc4ygAWZN90ACNgMDEAWyoklLkAYxgwLmMAGS4CnCwCMDp2HB8iUgBBTS1zSxs7SgA3LixuquIi9kCuOisAcS5pWABtAAYhWB2AOh2ARgBdXvQrQe0R4mtbKmqeHEV6Kzn0Rh4uAi3KABCdC4AC8IFhdPYAJKBGA4LQQLiQygAVQAyv1kTDGIjkQBhRzGJH7Gj0JiUM75WAGLTNVrtSJyWBOdwEaLTLQ9Ly9TkKeF_IiyYjQLilcYAJlOJ0-GDGVAKyxl33qfxOAA5JfF9uL4tk1QBObX6na6_YnHbZfUAdj2sBO8ROVuy2X2ADZ4jsdTtKaluPS7nIWW4Ol0cFT0CBgAjeNA_gBWIQAWhOcZ9TNg0XopR4pjUGcW1RjAAoQMtRVoAJRC9N0HBgdh0OCl4GlLSHEVi1Lobzc7tU6vC0US07imXoB7jBV0MewZW_bYnfXxcUJ2A67LxNX7B07Xdm8Up_Uuu26k7ZE5utXqnZWi692AXAQAbiAA).

From your example :

```js
yAxis: {
  type: 'category',
  data: ['Brazil', 'Indonesia', 'USA', 'India', 'China', 'World'],
  axisLabel: {
    show: false //hide yAxis label
  }
},
series: [
  {
    name: '2011',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [18203, 23489, 29034, 104970, 131744, 630230],
    label: {
      show: true,
      position: [5,-15], //put the label where you want
      formatter: function(params){
        return params.name //display series name
      }
    }
  },
]
```

[image]

Comment: Your method has helped me a lot, thank you!